# Display view on custom homepage

Tags: 7, views, routes

I have a site with custom home pages depending on role. The homepages are assigned with `hook_menu` (hook_menu associates a URL with a function that returns a `$html` string.)

For one particular role, I need to generate a homepage that incorporates a view. I am looking at a list of [views hooks](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/group/views_hooks/7), and not sure were to start.

In summary, how do I display a view that is generated from one of my hook_menu functions?

Edit:
I am currently looking into this code example from  http://lucor.github.com/2011/10/drupal7-how-display-block-programmatically/
The view is in now in a block.
I have not yet figured out what I either one of the parameters are suposed to be set to.

$block = block_load($module, $delta);
print render(_block_gAet_renderable_array( _block_render_blocks( array($block) )));

Comment: You need something like `Page output in Block`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have many ways to apply what you are looking for.

The easy way is to use [Context module](http://drupal.org/project/context) with [Empty Front Page module](http://drupal.org/project/empty_front_page)

Another way is to write your own module, something like the following code:

```
function myfront_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['frontpage'] = array(
    'title' => 'My homepage',
    'page callback' => 'myfront_front_page',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}

function myfront_front_page() {
  global $user;

  if (in_array('administrator', array_values($user->roles))) {
    return views_embed_view('view_name', 'display_id');
  }

  if (in_array('authenticated user', array_values($user->roles))) {
    return views_embed_view('view_name', 'display_id');  
  }

  if (in_array('role2', array_values($user->roles))) {
    return views_embed_view('view_name', 'display_id');  
  }

  if (in_array('role3', array_values($user->roles))) {
    return views_embed_view('view_name', 'display_id');  
  }

  return '';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could propably use

```
views_embed_view()
```

http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7

Answer (score 0):

You can try using context module (http://drupal.org/project/context) on your case or even use this for a better implementation of displaying different types of homepage depending on the user role without the hassle of using custom code.

You can preview what it can do here http://www.drupalove.com/drupal-video/context-module.